# Clicking Apps takes me to my Facebook page

Tags: facebook, redirect

I want to create an App for a Facebook page I'm developing but when I click on the link at the top called 'Apps' it just redirects me to the Facebook page. I have tried using different browsers and it does the same.

What is happening and how can it be resolved?

Can I use another Facebook account ie my own one to create the App and then add it to someone elses or does it have to be the owner of the Facebook page?

Colin.

Comment: Can you please elaborate on what you are doing and the steps that would allow me to create the issue?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Creating and managing a Facebook app from a Business Account](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/10805745/creating-and-managing-a-facebook-app-from-a-business-account)

Answer (score 1):

> Can I use another Facebook account ie my own one to create the App and then add it to someone elses or does it have to be the owner of the Facebook page?

You *have* to use your **personal** account. Only **user** accounts can be developers – not pages.

(And you have to verify your account with Facebook – either via text message to mobile, or credit card.)